# Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

Tags: jquery, product-list, category-listing, magento2.4.5

After Magento Upgrade in latest version product list page showing this error, please suggest me what we can take step to solve this error.

> ```
> jquery.js:10363 Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
>     at jQuery.fn.load (jquery.js:10363:23)
>     at new.html:185:27
>     at new.html:327:15
>     at Object.execCb (658fc906f1d52e7163f6385a220b823b.js:1696:33)
>     at Module.check (658fc906f1d52e7163f6385a220b823b.js:883:51)
>     at Module.<anonymous> (658fc906f1d52e7163f6385a220b823b.js:1139:34)
>     at 658fc906f1d52e7163f6385a220b823b.js:134:23
>     at 658fc906f1d52e7163f6385a220b823b.js:1189:21
>     at each (658fc906f1d52e7163f6385a220b823b.js:59:31)
>     at Module.emit (658fc906f1d52e7163f6385a220b823b.js:1188:17)
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Cause:**

Here's jquery 3 release note: https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/

> Removed deprecated event aliases
> (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2286)
>
> - `.load`, `.unload`, and `.error`, deprecated since jQuery 1.8, are no more.
> - Use `.on()` to register listeners.

**Solution:**

Search your custom/third-party modules code and replace the following deprecated excerpt:

```
$(window).load(function(){...});
```

with the following:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){ ...});
```